# Iterating C array-type container class from Lua using LuaBridge

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

This may be a newbie question, but I have not been able to find an answer with web searching that will even help me get started. I have a container class that at heart is a C-style array. For simplicity, let's depict it as this:

```
int *myArray = new int[mySize];
```

With `LuaBridge` we can assume I have successfully registered it as `my_array` in the global namespace. I would like to iterate over it from Lua like this:

```
for n in each(my_array) do
   ... -- do something with n
end
```

I'm guessing I probably need to register a function `each` in the global namespace. The problem is, I don't know what that function should look like in C++.

```
<return-type> DoForEach (<function-signature that includes luabridge::LuaRef>)
{
   // execute callback using luabridge::LuaRef, which I think I know how to do

   return <return-type>; //what do I return here?
}
```

This would perhaps have been easier if the code had used `std::vector` but I am trying to create a Lua interface to an existing code base that is complicated to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, because I have figured out that the question makes some incorrect assumptions. The existing code I was working with was a [true iterator class](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.5.html) (which is what it is called in the Lua docs) implemented in c++. These cannot be used with for loops, but that's how you get a callback function in c++.

To do what I was originally asking, we'll assume we've made `myArray` available as table `my_array` in lua using `LuaBridge` or whichever interface you prefer. (This may require a wrapper class.) You implement what I was asking entirely in Lua as follows. (This is almost exactly [an example in the Lua documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html), but somehow I missed it earlier.)

```lua
function each (t)
   local i = 0
   local n = table.getn(t)
   return function ()
            i = i + 1
            if i <= n then return t[i] end
          end
end

--my_array is a table linked to C++ myArray
--this can be done with a wrapper class if necessary
for n in each(my_array) do
   ... -- do something with n
end
```

If you want to provide the `each` function to every script you run, you add it directly from C++ as follows, before executing the script.

```cpp
luaL_dostring(l,
   "function each (t)" "\n"
      "local i = 0" "\n"
      "local n = table.getn(t)" "\n"
      "return function ()" "\n"
      "   i = i + 1" "\n"
      "   if i <= n then return t[i] end" "\n"
      "end" "\n"
   "end"
);
```